# How can I center the block of text without the next line being centered relative to the top line?

Tags: css, alignment, center

I need to center the text.  I used text-align center but the next line gets centered.  I need it to be aligned to the line on top.

```
<div class="box">
<div class="text">Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.
    Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.Some text.</div>
</div>
```

How can I center the block of text without the next line being centered relative to the top line?

http://jsfiddle.net/heQ9H/

Comment: Why don't you break the text in two different divs and assign them different values for 'text-align'?

Comment: Than how the text is "ALIGNED CENTER" if the second line you want to should start from left?

Comment: @kat_indo the amount of text is not consistent.  Sometimes it's a lot and sometimes it's just a few words.

Comment: @mr.alien that's what I wanted to know.  Is there a way to center a block of text while having the other lines follow the first one in terms of the alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One cheap way to do this is to wrap the text inside an element which you've already did, get the nearest width, where your text just ends perfect instead of wrapping to other line leaving a large space on the right, and than use `margin: auto;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/heQ9H/1/)

```
.text {
    width: 490px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/heQ9H/2/

Make the box 100% width of it's container.  The text then becomes centered inside of it with a set width of 510px.  I think this may be what you are looking for.

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
}
.text {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 510px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest example, all you need is the following:

```
.box {
    width: 510px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.text {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
}
```

You have a block container (`.box`) with a fixed width, and you center it with respect to its parent container by applying `margin: 0 auto`.

Depending on other formatting needs (for example, multiple background images or a hook for special JavaScript actions), the `.text` element may not be needed.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/heQ9H/3/